# Login django User without request

Tags: django, django-login

I am implementing oauth. I successfully did everything and finally I need to login user using login function. But the problem here is I didn't have any request to provide to login function. So, I made a request by importing requests. But that is not working properly. Can anyone please specify how to make a request so that I can login user perfectly. Is there any way to login user without request ??

If not can anyone make a perfect request for login ?? This is my request to the login function

```
s = requests.session()
        data = { 'username': user.username, 'password': user.password}
        s.post(url_path,data=data, verify=False)
        login(s, user)
```

verify=false // to prevent SSL error but I am still receiving it

and what about url_path ?? How actually to configure it??

Comment: This doesn't really make sense at all. The requests library has nothing to do with the Django request object. But how do you expect to log a user in without a request in the first place? Logging in means setting a session cookie, which requires a request.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I know it is not possible to login without request (but I can't assure it is correct so, I asked it to clarify). Can't I make a request using request library ?? for login ?

Comment: Then is there any way to make the user login with the user username and password ??

Comment: No because **those have nothing to do with each other** apart from both containing the word "request". They are not the same thing in any way at all.

Comment: Okay thankyou @DanielRoseman